# JPA: How to use @OneToMany with different target types

Tags: jpa

I have an entity Y and would like to embed a List of Y's in multiple unrelated entities X1, X2, ... The relationship should be bidirectional. Can this be done with @ManyToOne/@OneToMany? I tried

```
@Entity
class X1 {
   @Id
   String uuid_;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy="owner_")
   List< Y > yList_;
}

@Entity
class X2 {
   @Id
   String uuid_;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy="owner_")
   List< Y > yList_;
}

@Entity
class Y {
   @Id
   String uuid_;

   @ManyToOne
   String owner_;
}
```

but this does not work because String is not an entity and cannot be used as a relationship attribute.

I also tried to replace "String owner_" with "XBase owner_", using XBase as a @MappedSuperClass for X1 and X2. This produced the same error: "[class Y] uses a non-entity [class XBase] as target entity in the relationship attribute [field owner_]".

I wonder if it is at all possible to have different unrelated types at the "One" end of the relation. How would you implement this kind of relation with JPA?

Answer (score 0):

Since X1 and X2 are "unrelated types" there is no way to merge them in a single mapping. You need to have two distinct `@ManyToOne` mappings in Y:

```
@Entity
class Y {
    @Id
    String uuid_;

    @ManyToOne
    X1 owner1_;

    @ManyToOne
    X2 owner2_;
}
```

And then of course you need to adjust the value of the `mappedBy` attribute accordingly in the `@OneToMany` mappings.